# Update tzdata on RHEL4 with no RPM from RedHat

Tags: linux, redhat, java, timezone, rhel4

I have an RHEL4 server with no connectivity to Internet. (Of course, I can scp files into that server from my network). RHEL4 is out of support and RedHat no longer releases tzdata update RPMs for it. At least, I couldn't find an update RPM from RedHat.

My server runs Java 6u20. Is there a way to update the tzdata files using, let's say the timezone files provided at http://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2018-January/000048.html? Or any other mechanisms to update tzdata? Basically I need to get the latest DST info into that server.

Comment: You need to buy the appropriate support package, and even then they might not have it. You were supposed to have migrated away from RHEL4 several years ago. That said, backporting a noarch RPM is usually pretty easy. And I would not be terribly surprised if the RHEL6 or RHEL7 RPM installed properly without any issues.

Comment: We have the support package, but RedHat doesn't have it since RHEL4 is end of support since 2017. Migrated most of our customers, but a last few remain :-( I will try taking the noarch RPM for RHEL6 and try installing that. Thanks!

Comment: And remember that Java uses its own tzdata, not the system tzdata. If you used the system Java packages, it will be in `tzdata-java`. Otherwise, you'll probably have to chat with Oracle. Your Java version is also way past end of life.

Comment: That's another issue I have to deal with. The tzdata update is primarily for Java applications. By the way, the RHEL6/7 noarch RPM for tzdata doesn't install on RHEL4.

Comment: Try the RHEL 5 RPMs. The RPM format changed in RHEL 6 and isn't backward compatible.

Comment: RHEL5 RPMs got installed with no issues on RHEL4. The `tzdata` RPM took care of DST switches in the OS, `tzdata-java` installs the contents to `/usr/share/zoneinfo` which Java 6u20 didn't pick up. Had to copy the contents explicitly to `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/zi` for Java to pick up the timezone changes. (May be the TZ Updater tool for Java will do the same, but I couldn't get TZ Updater for Java 6, so had to resort to explicit copying). Thanks @MichaelHampton for the tips!

Comment: You're welcome. But keep in mind that this only buys you a few more months at most. RHEL 5 is also about to reach EOL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got to work this by installing RHEL5 `tzdata` RPMs on the RHEL4 box. The `tzdata-java` RPM contents had to be explicitly copied after installation to `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/zi` for Java to pick it up. (The RPM installs to `usr/share/zoneinfo`). Check the comments on the question as well, for some more details.